# JS как изменить позицию SVG элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, как изменить позицию SVG элемента? В моем случае это tspan, например мне его нужно поднять выше.

```
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">      
<text id="AAA" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" font-size="50" transform="rotate(-5 20,40)">
<tspan id="AAA" x="20%" y="45%" style="font-family: Pompadur; stroke:#000000;">ТЕКСТ</tspan>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменять координаты этого елемента, которые у вас описаны через `x="20%" y="45%`, используя метод *setAttribute()* :

```
document.querySelector('tspan').setAttribute('y','15%');
```